# Man's daughter is kidnapped for sex business and he goes for a revenge

Tags: identify-this-movie

In this movie, a husband and a wife who are separated, permit their daughter to go to Paris with her girl friend. Dad's a retired agent of some army section of the United States and has some very special skills.

In Paris, some men come to kidnap the girls, and in this scene, daughter talks to her father on the phone. She is scared and she's crying. Her father tells her to try to give him as much information as possible over the phone.

When they kidnap the girl, one of the kidnappers takes the phone, and says "Good luck" in response to father's threats about finding them.

Then father goes on to find his daughter and in this journey, he's able to find his daughter who's been used as a whore to be sold to a rich Arab guy.

A dialog that I remember is that he finds the boss of the kidnappers group, and wants to shoot him in the elevator. Boss says "Please don't take it personally, it's just business" or something like that, and father says: "for me, it's too personal".

What's the name of the movie?

Comment: *"who's been used as a whore"*  No.  At the auction, her price is higher because she is 'pure' (a virgin).  Raman *intends* to use her as his sex slave, but never gets the chance.

Comment: [I will find you... and I will kill you!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZOywn1qArI)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: Taken (2008) - Movie Poster]

[**Taken** (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0936501/)

> Bryan Mills, a retired CIA agent travels across Europe and relies on his old skills
>   to save his estranged daughter, Kim, who has been kidnapped while on a trip
>   to Paris.

From the movie's [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taken_%28film%29) entry, a description of the kidnapping:

> Kim is pulled out violently from under the bed, and she complies with
>   her father's instructions before the phone is found. Bryan warns the
>   person over the phone that they have this one chance to release his
>   daughter, or else he will begin hunting them down and killing them.
>   He's told "good luck" and the connection is terminated.

These scenes describe how he tracks down his daughter:

> Bryan infiltrates Saint-Clair's mansion, where a large party is the
>   facade for an auction of girls in the basement. Bryan forces a Middle
>   Eastern bidder to purchase his daughter, but is captured after they
>   exit the room. Bryan frees himself and kills Saint-Clair's henchmen.
>   He forces Saint-Clair to reveal where Kim has been taken before
>   killing him. Bryan races the luxury yacht owned by Raman, a sheikh,
>   and boards it.

The dialogue you remember from the movie? That takes place when Bryan corners Saint-Clair in his mansion and extracts his daughter's location from him.

> Saint-Clair pleads for his life: ***Please understand. It was all
>   business, it wasn't personal.***
>
> Bryan (coldly): ***It was all personal to me.***
>
> He shoots Saint-Clair dead.

Watch the [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CG5-bEGOKM) to confirm your movie.